# loading html content into iframe fails in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome

I have made an HTML page with the following jQuery script.

```
function clickbutton() {
 frameContent = $('#iframeID').contents().find('body').html();
 $("#paste").html(frameContent);
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
This is a page with an IFRAME.<br>
<IFRAME id="iframeID" src="otherpage.html" height="600" width="600"></IFRAME><br>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="clickbutton()"/><br>
<div id="paste"></div>
```

The script reads the content of the `otherpage.html` when the button is clicked. 
This works perfectly in IE and Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Why is this not working in Chrome, and are there any workarounds?

Comment: Please define what doesn't work. What happens or doesn't happen. Whether you get any error messages (Ctrl + Shift + J should open the error console)

Comment: Right click anywhere on the page and click "Inspect Element". Go to the Console section and see if there are any specific errors.

Comment: Chrome comes up with this error: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Peter/Documents/otherpage.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Peter/Documents/test.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.       That is weird, because they are both in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work for me: http://www.jsfiddle.net/d6SNB/2/

Comment: yep... works for me too but not sure whats his actual problem yet :)

Comment: It works for me too, but not on my hard drive. I'm not sure, but I think my code will work on an actual server.